# FFT for non power-of-2 input length

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I am writing a Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) in Python and facing problems with input data lengths that are not powers of 2. I came across recommendations to pad such inputs with zeros to reach the nearest power of 2, but I found the results are much different compared to standard implementations (numpy)

Here's my implementation of the FFT:

```
def myfft(x):
    N = len(x)
    if N <= 1:
        return x
    evens = myfft(x[0::2])
    odds = myfft(x[1::2])
    t = np.exp(-2j * np.pi * np.arange(N) / N)
    f = np.concatenate([evens + t[:N//2] * odds,
                        evens + t[N//2:] * odds])
    return f
```

This gives the same result as numpy.fft.fft() when the input length is a power of 2, but gives a different result for zero padding input.

```
output1 = np.fft.fft([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
output2 = myfft([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0])

output1: [28  -3.5+7.3j -3.5+2.8j -3.5+0.8j -3.5-0.8j -3.5-2.8j -3.5-7.3j        ]
output2: [28  -9.7+4j   -4-4j      1.7-4j    4         1.7+4j   -4+4j     -9.7-4j]
```

Is zero-padding a good approach for handling non power-of-2 input lengths in FFT? If so, what is the correct way to implement it?

Comment: numpy doesn't convert to a power of 2, it uses a different algorithm than the basic power of 2 FFT algorithm.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77118/non-power-of-2-ffts

Comment: What you have to remember when using FFTs is that there is an implicit periodicity in your dataset with the supplied data pattern repeated in a cyclic loop. Your data is therefore equivalent to ...01234567012345670.... vs ...12345671234567... and numpy has done a radix 7 FFT here. Making an FFT deliver an accurate DFT is distinctly non-trivial - people usually zero pad with almost as many zeroes as they have data and in addition apply a window function and/or a compact convolution to the source data. Numerical Recipes isn't a bad place to look for some real world guidance on this.